# Three js Obj loader Rotation

Tags: javascript, three.js

Ive made a stick in the Three js editor, after loading it with the following code i can position it but not rotate it.
Its a stick made of 4 meshes, so i probably have to make a rotation point but i cant figure out how i get that to work.

The ideal situation :

```
   x   -------
```

The x represents the point where i want to rotate the dashes(stick) around

can anyone help me?

thx in advance

```
var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.load("scene.json", function ( obj )
{
    stick =obj;

    scene.add( stick );
    stick.position.z = -9;
    stick.position.y = .4;
    stick.children[3].rotation.x(45);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand aright, you have an object with 4 children that are meshes.

```
Object3D
  -Mesh
  -Mesh
  -Mesh
  -Mesh
```

First, I would translate all the children, and then rotate the parent object.

```
for(var i=0; i<stick.children.length; i++) {
    stick.children[i].position.set(0, 0.4, -9); // or another offset
}

stick.rotateX( 45 * Math.PI / 180 ); // make sure to use Radians
```

Comment: thx for your answer. but isnt this gonna set every mesh at the same position. the meshes form a stick that indiviualy should have diffrent positions from eachother

Comment: Well, I don't know how the meshes are positioned. You could also do a relative translation of the meshes: `stick.children[i].translateY(0.4); stick.children[i].translateZ(-9);` or  `stick.children[i].position.add(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0.4, -9));`
And of course, you can set them individually without using a loop.